# How to pass raw strings or integers into django template filters?

Tags: python, django

I have a string which needs to passed into a django template filter. But just the string alone, there are no django models involved, and I think this is what's causing the issue.

```
var pk = "123";
var age = "{{ pk|pk_into_age }}";
```

In my django template filter code:

```
def pk_into_age(pk):
    timestamp = Model.objects.get(pk=int(pk)).timestamp
    return humanizeTimeDiff(timestamp) // Ex: "5 hours ago"
return timestamp
```

However this is not working, the error is that the "pk" value is just an empty string "", which is not the case, it's not grabbing the pk string literal from above.

Thanks fro helping

Comment: can you show how you have called the filter in the template?

Comment: Oops I made a typo above, edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the template filter in a wrong way. Please see below:
You can not pass the javascript variable into the template filter, passed the variable from context.

```
<script>
    var age = "{{ pk|pk_into_age }}";
</script>
```

Assuming `pk` variable exists in the context. Or hardcode the pk value as:

```
var age = "{{ '123'|pk_into_age }}";
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, how to I pass the js variable then? I can't hardcode it, because it's dynamic among many models.

Comment: where does the pk value come from? If you are defining it by your self then you can directly use it in filter see updated answer

Comment: Here is how i'm defining it: var pk = news[index].pk; News is a BIG json object, index is an index to that model in the json, pk is the pk field.

Comment: Does `news` exists in context?

Comment: news is defined, as a js variable, var news = {{ blah|jsonify|blah }};

Comment: I think you are creating json using some model objects right? you can directly use the object to pass its pk in the filter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21877/discussion-between-aamir-adnan-and-lucas-ou-yang)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use javascript variable in a template filter, because javascript runs on the client side, while templates are generated on the server side.

As far as I know, there is no way, to bypass this problem, without communicating with the server again.

So, to pass a javascript variable to a template filter, you may, for example, use an ajax request. Write additional view, which processes given pk and returns a plain template, without html headers, just with the data you need.

OR... if you don't need to communicate with user to get "news" object, just retrieve news.age in the view.